# Issue using P:commandLink value attribute

Tags: html, css, jsf, user-interface, primefaces

I have p:commandLink in xhtml page

I have given the value to value attribute and image to styleClass attribute.
It displays value on image. (Overriding the image with value)

How to display only image on it?

XHTML code:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{userController.createNewUser}"
               update=":userRightPaneForm" 
               styleClass="newButtonLnk"
               value="New">
</p:commandLink>
```

CSS Code:

```
.newButtonLnk {  width: 40px; height: 17px;
                 background: url('../images/buttons/new_off.png')
                 no-repeat;
                 display: inline-block;
}
.newButtonLnk:hover{ width: 40px; height: 17px;
                     background: url('../images/buttons/new_on.png')
                     no-repeat;
}
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `value` attribute into `""`

Like this :  `value=""`

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{userController.createNewUser}"
           update=":userRightPaneForm" 
           styleClass="newButtonLnk"
           value="">
</p:commandLink>
```